# Show Fréchet differentiable convex function satisfies property.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be convex, i.e.,
>   $$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y), \ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n, \ \lambda \in (0,1).$$
>
> Suppose $f(\cdot)$ is also (Fréchet) differentiable. Show that 
>   $$f(x) + f_x(x)(y-x) \leq f(y), \ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R^n}.$$

Here, $f_x(x)$ denotes the Fréchet derivative, so we know that
$$\lim_{||y|| \to 0} \frac{|f(x+y)-f(x) - f_x(x) \cdot y|}{||y||} = 0.$$

I tried rearranging things to make the problem nicer, but I have no intuition on how to proceed with this one. If you rewrite the second line as 
$$f_x(x) \leq \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$ it kind of looks like MVT might come into play, but I could not see where to apply this. Hints please?

Comment: Oh for a second I thought you had it already. I'm writing a solution now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is convex. Then for any $\lambda\in(0,1)$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have
$$ f(\lambda y + (1-\lambda)x)\le \lambda f(y) + (1-\lambda)f(x). $$
Rearranging this yields
$$ \frac{f(x + \lambda(y-x)) - f(x)}{\lambda} \le f(y) - f(x).$$
Taking the limit as $\lambda\longrightarrow 0$,
$$f'(x)(y-x)\le f(y) - f(x). $$
Here, I am using the fact that Frechet differentiable implies Gateuax differentiable, and I am abusing the notation $f'(x)$ here.

Comment: Your notation is confusing me a little... How did you get $f'(x)(y-x)$?

Comment: That's the definition of Gateuax differentiability, or simply, directional derivative. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative

Answer (score 1):

Since $f:R^{n} \rightarrow R$, the Frechet derivative is simply the gradient.  You can find a proof of this first order characterization of convexity of differentiable functions on page 70 of the textbook on Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe (with a free download)

http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/